# Is there any function in pine script to add integers of a number

Tags: pine-script, stock, trading

I am looking for a function to add integers of a number in pine script on tradingview.

For example, if a number is 125 then function should return 1+2+5=8

I also want this sum to divide by a number, say 2. If it is divisible then only that number will be used otherwise it will be false

Answer (score 1):

This function will add up the numbers.

```
f_add(_number) =>
    var float sum = 0
    a = str.split(str.replace_all(str.tostring(_number),'.',''),'')
    for i = 0 to array.size(a) - 1
        sum += str.tonumber(array.get(a,i))
```

Example script

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

f_add(_number) =>
    var float sum = 0
    a = str.split(str.replace_all(str.tostring(_number),'.',''),'')
    for i = 0 to array.size(a) - 1
        sum += str.tonumber(array.get(a,i))

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(f_add(123.49)))
```

Not sure what you mean by "*I also want this sum to divide by a number, say 2. If it is divisible then only that number will be used otherwise it will be false*".
Can you give an example?

Modulo example

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

f_add(_number) =>
    var float sum = 0
    a = str.split(str.replace_all(str.tostring(_number),'.',''),'')
    for i = 0 to array.size(a) - 1
        sum += str.tonumber(array.get(a,i))

f_divisible(_number, _divisor) => _number % _divisor == 0

if barstate.islast
    mysum = f_add(123.22)
    divisor = 2
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(mysum), color=f_divisible(mysum,divisor)?color.green:color.red)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try it out.

Comment: When I say sum divided by a number - For example, No is 125 & it sums to 8. So it is divisible by 2. So this condition is true & I will have further operations on that number. If it is not divisible by 2 then it is false & that Number will not be considered for example 124 (sum=7)

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want a way to check for divisibility of a number? Or do you want to incorporate that somehow in that f_add() function? If the latter, please explain how. If the first you can just use the Modulo (integer remainder) % operator. Example added to my answer.

Comment: I want divisibility of sum of integers. As I mentioned if number is 125, sum of its integer is 8. I want to check whether this sum(8) is divisible by 2. For this number it is true, but for 124 where sum is 7 it is false.

Comment: Then I guess your problem is solved with the latest example in my answer?

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out (Not done yet with your updated post)